# Can't connect laptop on domain to private network (home wireless)

Tags: networking, domain

Please, help. Tried most of the troubleshooting that I came across Google. None of them worked so far. I can not connect neither via wireless nor cable to my home internet. Uninstalled the drivers, reinstalled. Turned off firewall. 
It did not connect to another private wireless that I tried. It did connect to public wireless which did not require password. It connects to the internet when it is on domain network flawlessly. Can't figure out what the problem is. Planning to remove from domain and place in workgroup, then try again.

Any help appreciated? Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention. The laptop is Lenovo T410 with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure you don't have a static IP? You would need to check in Network Adapters and make sure TCP/IP Protocol version 4 is set to get dynamic addresses. Also check for alternate DNS Servers in the Advanced section.

Run ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew.

Potentially Group Policy is applied to your computer to restrict off-site internet access.